# Windows Media Capture -402587628 error "The text associated with this error code could not be found."

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

```
private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
        {

            if (_mediaCapture == null)
            {

                // Get available devices for capturing pictures
                var allVideoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

                // Get the desired camera by panel
                DeviceInformation cameraDevice =
                    allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null &&
                    x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);

                // If there is no camera on the specified panel, get any camera
                cameraDevice = cameraDevice ?? allVideoDevices.FirstOrDefault();

                if (cameraDevice == null)
                {
                    //ShowMessageToUser("No camera device found.");
                    Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found.");
                    return;
                }

                // Create MediaCapture and its settings
                _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                // Register for a notification when video recording has reached the maximum time and when something goes wrong
                //_mediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCapture_RecordLimitationExceeded;

                var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

                // Initialize MediaCapture
                try
                {
                    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
                    _isInitialized = true;
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    //ShowMessageToUser("The app was denied access to the camera");
                    Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception when initializing MediaCapture with {0}: {1}", cameraDevice.Id, ex.ToString());
                }

                // If initialization succeeded, start the preview
                if (_isInitialized)
                {
                    // Figure out where the camera is located
                    if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
                    {
                        // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                        _externalCamera = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Camera is fixed on the device
                        _externalCamera = false;

                        // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                        //_mirroringPreview = (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                    }

                    //await StartPreviewAsync();

                    //UpdateCaptureControls();
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem appears in the second "catch" statement while trying to InitializeAsync mediaCapture.

How can I check what's wrong, if it doesn't provide me any error details?

Comment: This code is working just fine for me. Did you set your Microphone and Webcam Capabilities in your app manifest?

Comment: Yep, I did. Are there any things that could block using camera on Windows Phone 10? On PC it works well...